# Accessing object passed from component in Angular

Tags: json, angular, object, ngfor

I have following class named `Enumeration`:

```
export class Enumeration {
    name: string;
    values: Object;
}
```

Now in my component I have created my object and filled with data.

in his template I have something like this:

```
<div class="card-item-content">
  <span>{{enumeration | json}}</span>
</div>
```

this works normaly and I can see this:

```
{ "name": "employee-type", "values": [ null, { "id": 1, "text": "Employee" }, { "id": 2, "text": "Contractor" }, { "id": 3, "text": "Newjoiner" }, null, { "id": 5, "text": "Consultant" }, { "id": 6, "text": "GCP" }, { "id": 7, "text": "Career Counselor" } ] }
```

but when I try

```
{{enumeration.name | json}} or {{enumeration.values | json}}
```

I got this error message:

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

when I do :

```
*ngFor="let enum of enumeration.values"
```

it will loops 8 times but first span is empty then it goes 3 times with

```
[object Object]
```

an then another one empty span and then 3 times previous.

The point is I want to access for each *not* null objects in `values` object property , propertyies `text` and `id`.

so the result should be 6 spans with this content:

```
Employee 1
Contractor 2
Newjoiner 3
Consultant 5
GCP 6
Career Counselor 7
```

Can anybody give me some hints please?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

So I did it this way only in template.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let enum of enumeration?.values">
   <span *ngIf="enum">{{enum?.text}} : {{enum?.id}}</option>
</ng-container>
```

This is my `ngOnInit`:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    if (this.id != null) {
      const enumName = employeeDetailsEnumMapping.get(this.id);
      this.enumsService.getEnums().subscribe(data => {
        this.enumeration = data.get(enumName);
        if (this.enumeration == null) {
          console.error(`missing enum ${this.id}`);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

and when I added:

```
this.enumeration.values = this.enumeration.values.filter(x => x != null);
```

it says:

```
'filter' property does not exist on type 'Object';
```

It helped me to solve this problem. But actually filter way would look better I guess.

Comment: You can just filter null values like this values = this.enumeration.values.filter(v => v) and use the result in *ngFor loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I guess you want is to remove all `null` values from the array, so that you can properly access the objects in the array, so you could do this for example in your subscribe:

```
.subscribe(data => {
  this.enumeration = data;
  this.enumeration.values = this.enumeration.values.filter(x => x != null);        
})
```

Then your iteration should work fine, using the safe navigation operator to safeguard `null` values (if this is async)

```
<div *ngFor="let enum of enumeration?.values">
  {{enum.text}}
</div>
```

### [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aKuDnruJh4dPz03kNCCg?p=preview)

Comment: Hi. I have edited my question. U can check. But thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem, glad to hear you found a solution to your problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

the json object should be enclosed by `{}` or `[]`.

```
{{enumeration.name | json}} or {{enumeration.values | json}}
```

is not a valid json, the result therefore is `undefined`.

Comment: u mean where? like in result?

Answer (score -1):

```
{{(enumeration | json)?.name}}
```

Firstly get the json, then try to get into a variable. Does it work?

Comment: this did nothing

Comment: You don't seem to know what JSON is.